# Mod Rewrite - Disable it for specific folders

Tags: php, css, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following file structure

|---api

|---css

|---img

|---js

|index.php

|rewrite.php

|book.php

What I basically do is, redirect every single request to rewrite.php and then based on first parameter of request URI, `include` the corresponding page through PHP.

**My rewrite.php file:**

```
 $path = rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/");
 $elements = explode('/', $path); 

 if($elements[1] == "about-us") //Something like www.domain.com/about-us
 {
    require_once("about-us.php");
 }
```

For booking, I check as following: (Something like www.domain.com/city/service)

```
 if($elements[1] == "somecityname" && $elements[2] != "")
 {
    $_GET["serviceID"] = Service ID of service retrieved through DB;
    require_once("book.php");
 }
```

But book.php file includes the CSS and JS files as `www.domain.com/city/css` and `www.domain.com/city/js` and hence comes up with the error 404.

There is some problem with my HTACCESS. My current file is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(pg|api|css|js|lib|customerapi|agentapi)[/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#rewrite to https and www
# Redirect to domain with www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|\d+)\.
RewriteRule .* http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#rewrite url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /rewrite.php [L,QSA]
```

Please help me where am I going wrong.

Comment: I also have a `RewriteEngine Off` .htaccess in CSS and JS folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But book.php file includes the CSS and JS files as www.domain.com/city/css and www.domain.com/city/js and hence comes up with the error 404.

That I believe is due to your use of relative paths in including `css` and `js` files.

For that you can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

---

**EDIT:** To exclude certain folders have this rule just below `RewriteEngine` line:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(pg|css|js|exclude1|exclude2)[/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: Bingo! I resolved it in the morning after posting the question. But you got it right too :)

Comment: How can I exclude a folder called 'pg' from rewriting? I added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pg(/|$)` before all RewriteCond but it ain't happening?

Comment: Check my updated htaccess. unfortunately even after adding that line, payment gateway is not working. It is not generating checksum

Comment: I can't comment on checksum etc but that rule I provided in **EDIT** section definitely skips all the folders if 1) That rule is just below `RewriteEngine` line and 2) There is no .htaccess in any sub folders.

Comment: Yes I removed all .htaccess files from subfolders. Please once check my htaccess in the question. I have updated it with your suggestions.

Comment: Yes that looks alright to me. You can tweak a bit `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(pg|css|js|exclude1|exclude2)[/\s?] [NC]` But this won't make much difference.

Comment: Last help, the domain.com and the IP Address of the server get redirected to *www.* followed by the requested URI. How can I avoid redirection of IP Address to www? Current line in htaccess - `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Comment: Change condition to `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|\d+)\.`

Comment: Still adding www to IP Address

Comment: I think browser cache issue or some other code/rule issue. But this works on my Apache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80017/discussion-between-rishi-jasapara-and-anubhava).

Comment: How can I transfer all calls from http to https in the current htaccess?